# How to enable user to drag/drop WPF user controls anywhere on the page?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, drag-and-drop

Now that I can make useful user controls in WPF (thanks to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507832/how-to-read-a-passed-parameter-in-a-wpf-usercontrol/508738#508738)) I want to be able to put numerous user controls on one page in two columns and enable the user to be able to move them around according to preference, dragging the ones they use the most to the top, etc.

Can anyone point me to code, tutorials, etc. which do this? I can imagine this has been made quite easy to do in WPF.

Comment: "I can imagine that this has been made quite easy to do in WPF."  Yes, you can imagine it.  You'll have to. :)

Comment: [AvalonDock](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/AvalonDock) appears to be the most popular solution today, for user-draggable docking. It is part of [2nd most popular WPF Nuget download](https://nugetmusthaves.com/article/top-wpf-libraries) - [xceed's Extended.WPF.Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also [How can I drag and drop items between data bound ItemsControls?](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53) by Bea Stollnitz.

The article talks about a reusable set of adorners that enable drag-n-drop between controls.

It's somewhat advanced, but very useful.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/marcelolr/archive/2006/03/02/542641.aspx) is a blog post to get you started on drag drop functionality in WPF.

Have Fun.

Answer (score 1):

A series of blog [posts](http://blog.pixelingene.com/?p=9) that deal with Drag and Drop using attached properties.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you need but it might get you close!!!

[Martin Grayson](http://blogs.msdn.com/mgrayson/default.aspx) has a project on Codeplex called [Blacklight](http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/)... Check out the Drag dock Panel!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an easy way to accomplish this as well and came across the following web page: http://dotnetslackers.com/ADO_NET/re-191632_Generic_WPF_Drag_and_Drop_Adorner.aspx It looks like there are some nice features of this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, there is a great library on codeproject that has a DragCanvas which enables you to drag any controls placed on it:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFJoshSmith.aspx

It also contains a CenteredContentControl if you want to make "attachments" between controls.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

```
private void Control_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        isDragging = true;
        var draggableControl = sender as UserControl;
        clickPosition = e.GetPosition(this.Parent as UIElement);
        var transform = RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
        if (transform != null) {
            clickPosition.X -= transform.X;
            clickPosition.Y -= transform.Y;
        }
        draggableControl.CaptureMouse();
}
```