# How can we provide different Tap event functionality for a usercontrol in wp8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

In my Windows Phone 8 application, i am using one usercontrol to display in all pages. 
UserControl XAML code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="ExpiryPopUp_Container" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Border x:Name="Delete" Background="#FFFFFFFF" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" BorderBrush="#8ca5b9" BorderThickness="2" Height="180" Canvas.Left="58" Canvas.Top="320" Grid.Row="1" Width="360">
        <Canvas>
            <Border Background="{StaticResource LeftNavBackground}" Height="50" CornerRadius="10,10,0,0" Width="356">
                <TextBlock FontSize="26" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf#Open Sans Regular" Text="Alert" Width="356" Canvas.Top="10" Height="28"/>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Text="Oops! Something went wrong with network connection" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="22" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf#Open Sans Regular" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="{StaticResource BlueText}" Canvas.Top="62" Width="356"/>
            <Border x:Name="BorderOk" Background="{StaticResource buttonBackground}" Height="40" Width="98" Canvas.Left="132" Canvas.Top="125" Tap="BorderOk_Tap_1">
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="Ok" FontSize="26" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf#Open Sans Regular" Canvas.Top="14" Margin="10,5,10,2"/>
            </Border>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Canvas>
```

For Border with name BorderOk has Tap event. I am using this usercontrol throughout my application,almost in all pages. Once user tap on the border it will navigate to MainPage.xaml, but my problem is in some pages i want it to not navigate (means the functionality of tap event to be changed). So can i achieve this by using same usercontrol?If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is adding a parameter to your user control, for example "shouldNavigate" and set it everytime you use it(or have a default value of true and change it to false in your special situation). Use the value of this parameter in Tap event.

It's been discussed a number of times on SO, check it out: [How to read a passed parameter in a WPF UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507832/how-to-read-a-passed-parameter-in-a-wpf-usercontrol)